# loop in R with irregular dates

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series

I need to loop between dates in R.

```
for (i in seq(from=as.Date('2010-09-01'), to=as.Date('2009-09-05'), by='days')) { functions..}

35215 2010-09-03 150.46666670  1.306040e+00  1.409377e+00
35216 2010-09-03  48.23333333  7.698516e-01  8.530168e-01
35217 2010-09-03  10.26666667  3.574390e-01  4.051909e-01
35218 2010-09-03  20.86666667  5.217803e-01  6.078080e-01
35219 2010-09-03  37.73333333  5.716991e-01  6.126749e-01
35220 2010-09-03  40.23333333  7.574963e-01  8.339187e-01
35221 2010-09-03  44.96666667  7.061393e-01  7.462744e-01
35222 2010-09-03   7.33333333  2.354582e-02  4.345455e-02
35265 2010-09-06  76.46666667  9.257791e-01  1.033987e+00
35266 2010-09-06  55.26666667  7.511269e-01  8.377076e-01
35267 2010-09-06 114.33333330  1.079948e+00  1.074174e+00
35268 2010-09-06 142.23333330  1.283063e+00  1.237034e+00
35269 2010-09-06  68.83333333  7.508504e-01  8.042198e-01
35270 2010-09-06 175.53333330  1.355821e+00  1.351706e+00
35271 2010-09-06 268.60000000  1.555365e+00  1.963321e+00
35272 2010-09-06  90.76666667  1.085602e+00  1.236237e+00
35274 2010-09-06  98.46666667  1.063891e+00  1.076711e+00
35275 2010-09-06  52.43333333  6.977093e-01  7.280275e-01
```

the loop works as long as the next date in the dataset is just one day after i, but it stops when there is a weekend, and I don't have data during the weekend.
How can I loop between this range of dates and perform a function using subsets according to each date?